# Filtering undefined from array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am having trouble sorting out the `undefined` from the array of objects that was crated from local storage. Lets assume that this array of of objects is localStorage:

`var arrObject = [{date: undefined, bus_name: Thomas #1};...]` Assume this has 2 dates that had undefined.

I want to be able to filter out the date that has undefined and the bus_name that is within the date so for example, if I used filter for an array of objects before sorting them, then `{date: undefined, bus_name: Thomas #1}` will not be included in the array that will be sorted.

How would I accomplish this?

Thanks!

UPDATE: 3/5/20

How would I accomplish this if I have more than 2 columns, lets say I have at least 5, I want to filter and sort date as well as only output date and bus_name

`var arrObject = [{date: undefined, bus_name: Thomas #1, bus_driver: Thomas, time_start: 9AM, time_end: 5PM};...]`

Output: `{date: ..., bus_name:...}; {...}`

Comment: `arrObject.filter(e => e.date)`

Comment: @danh So I made a function that would create points for that array, how would I implement that onto there.
`function getPointsTable(data, points) {
    for (let i in data) {
        let point = [];
        let cols = Object.keys(data[0]);
        for (let j of cols) {
            point.push(j === 'date' ? Number(new Date(data[i][j])) : data[i][j]);
        }
        points.push(point)
    }
    return points
}`

Comment: @MarkAAvila Just to make sure I understand the question, you need to filter out all objects where `date: undefined` so that the array will only contain objects that have a date?

Comment: @JoshuaKleveter yes, dont forget that it will filter out the date that's undefined and the bus_name that contains it for example '{date: undefined, bus_name: Thomas #1}' should not be in the sorted array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you should provide filter with condation field (one is date, another is bus_name )

anyway i want clear it out that :--

```
 i) arrObject.filter(e => e.date)  // with this all {date: undefined } contain object will be filter and get data which have actual date value 

 ii) arrObject.filter(e => e.date === undefined) // give filter result with all date undefined  
iii) arrObject.filter(e => e.date === undefined && e.bus_name ) or arrObject.filter(e => e.date && e.bus_name)
```

which one of the result you are expecting

Comment: The goal is for filter to filter out the date thats undefined or empty along with bus_name, since they are within the same array so Im assuming that the third option is the correct one.

Comment: i think your sort portion you achieve by this    arrObject1.filter((d) =>{ return d.date}).sort((a,b)=>new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date))

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method:

```js
const arrObject = [
{date: undefined, bus_name: 'Thomas #1'},
{date: '2012-02-11', bus_name: 'Thomas #2'},
{date: '2012-02-02', bus_name: 'Thomas #3'},
{date: '2012-02-04', bus_name: 'Thomas #4'},
{date: undefined, bus_name: 'Thomas #5'},
{date: '2012-02-03', bus_name: 'Thomas #6'},
{date: '2012-02-03', bus_name: 'Thomas #7'},
]
function formatTheDate (str){
  //your format here
  let FormatedDate = "new Date format" + str 
  return FormatedDate
}

let newArray = arrObject.filter( obj => {
  obj.formattedDate = formatTheDate(obj.date)
  //behave same as obj.date != undefined
  return obj.date
}).sort((a,b)=>{
  return Date.parse(a.date) - Date.parse(b.date)
})

console.log(newArray);
```

---

EDIT: updated the answer to return sorted result based on the date;

Comment: This worked pretty well! Thank You. What if I wanted to sort the array by dates instead dates value being foo and bar its "2012-03-03" and "2013-02-02" instead.

Comment: @MarkAAvila Descending or Ascending ?

Comment: From early to latest (2012-2020) for example

Comment: @MarkAAvila the date format matters, being timespan, being Date(), or string. what kind of date is yours?

Comment: the dates are with " " so strings

Comment: @MarkAAvila updated the answer accordingly; you ca change inner logic of sort function per requirement. but this is a was naive solution that came to my mind; there could be better, more efficient ways too;

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Mhmdz_A Last question: Where would I place the date format so it will convert the current format to MM/DD/YY or MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: @MarkAAvila my code doesn't work as expected if the are two exact dates right now; can be that an issue?

Comment: There are duplicates of the same dates but different bus names and I need it for table plotting, but yes that can be an issue