# Filtering undefined or empty strings from array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, object, undefined

So I am having trouble creating a function that will filter and sort dates and its data to be placed in an array of objects. The issue I am having is a different but similar scenario. The original question was taken from here: [Filtering undefined from array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60514157/filtering-undefined-from-array-of-objects-in-javascript/60514506#60514506)

Lets say that var arrObject has more than 2 items in an array. See code below.I want to filter any empty string or undefined values and with any items in the array and sort then asc. order by dates. In the new array, I want to output only date and bus_name. Note the names in the array are different, I want to name then in a different name such as this output:

`{Date: '2012-02-11', busName: 'Thomas #2'}. ...`

How would I accomplish this?

Thank you!

````
{date: " ", bus_name: 'Thomas #1', driver_name: 'Sam', time_start: '9AM', time_end: '5PM'},
{date: '2012-02-11', bus_name: 'Thomas #2', driver_name: 'Samantha', time_start: '8AM', time_end: '4PM'},
{date: '2011-02-02', bus_name: 'Thomas #3', driver_name: 'Peter', time_start: '12PM', time_end: '7PM'},
{date: '2010-06-04', bus_name: 'Thomas #4', driver_name: 'Eddie', time_start: '11AM', time_end: '6PM'},
{date: " ", bus_name: 'Thomas #5', driver_name: 'Raul', time_start: '4AM', time_end: '1PM'},
{date: '2014-04-03', bus_name: 'Thomas #6', driver_name: 'Jessie', time_start: '5AM', time_end: '2PM',
]

function fancySort(array){
   let arrayCopy = array.slice(0);
  //your sort logic can be replaced here
  arrayCopy.sort();

  return arrayCopy
}

let newArray = arrObject.filter( obj => {
  //behave same as obj.date != undefined
  return obj.date
})

let sortedDates = fancySort(newArray.map(obj => Date.parse(obj.date)));

let sortedObjArray = sortedDates.map( date=>{
  let tempObj;
  newArray.some( na=> {
    tempObj = na;
    return Date.parse(na.date) == date
  })
  return tempObj;
})

console.log(sortedObjArray);```
````

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: There's no falsy values (the space is not a falsy value) in the objects ..?

Comment: `dataSet.filter(x => x.date.trim().length > 0)` - This is only if `date` is 
`1. not undefined`   
`2. is type of string`   
`3. date is known to either be empty or white space`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter unwanted parts, map new objects with wanted properties and sort the array by `date`.

```js
var array = [{ date: " ", bus_name: 'Thomas #1', driver_name: 'Sam', time_start: '9AM', time_end: '5PM' }, { date: '2012-02-11', bus_name: 'Thomas #2', driver_name: 'Samantha', time_start: '8AM', time_end: '4PM' }, { date: '2011-02-02', bus_name: 'Thomas #3', driver_name: 'Peter', time_start: '12PM', time_end: '7PM' }, { date: '2010-06-04', bus_name: 'Thomas #4', driver_name: 'Eddie', time_start: '11AM', time_end: '6PM' }, { date: " ", bus_name: 'Thomas #5', driver_name: 'Raul', time_start: '4AM', time_end: '1PM' }, { date: '2014-04-03', bus_name: 'Thomas #6', driver_name: 'Jessie', time_start: '5AM', time_end: '2PM' }],
    result = array
        .filter(o => o.date !== ' ')
        .map(({ date, bus_name }) => ({ date, bus_name }))
        .sort((a, b) => a.date.localeCompare(b.date));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Lets say for an example, that the array is store in local storage containing var array, I create a var for it to JSON parse the local storage and now how would I return the column names within the local storage

Comment: don't know. haven't work with local storrage. this may be another question.