# Removing filtered array of objects Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

From the refer link, I was able to get the sorting and column working. Now there are 2 things I need assist on.

First, is how to change the name of the column to a name I choose, (e.g, date -> Date, and bus_name -> busName.

Second, is to remove filtered arrays. I used the accepted answer, and it worked but it filtered the empty string at the end of the array. I want to remove any empty strings and or undefined values in the array without affecting the original array I mapped.

This was the accepted answer:

```js
var array = [{ date: " ", bus_name: 'Thomas #1', driver_name: 'Sam', time_start: '9AM', time_end: '5PM' }, { date: '2012-02-11', bus_name: 'Thomas #2', driver_name: 'Samantha', time_start: '8AM', time_end: '4PM' }, { date: '2011-02-02', bus_name: 'Thomas #3', driver_name: 'Peter', time_start: '12PM', time_end: '7PM' }, { date: '2010-06-04', bus_name: 'Thomas #4', driver_name: 'Eddie', time_start: '11AM', time_end: '6PM' }, { date: " ", bus_name: 'Thomas #5', driver_name: 'Raul', time_start: '4AM', time_end: '1PM' }, { date: '2014-04-03', bus_name: 'Thomas #6', driver_name: 'Jessie', time_start: '5AM', time_end: '2PM' }],
    result = array
        .filter(o => o.date !== ' ')
        .map(({ date, bus_name }) => ({ date, bus_name }))
        .sort((a, b) => a.date.localeCompare(b.date));

console.log(result);
```

On the filter part, I want to be able to filter and remove the ' ', 0, and/or undefined from the array that is being mapped. How would I do this? I recommend using the accepted answer I used. The array I am using is in localStorage.

Follow criteria from the link below!

Refer to this link: [Filtering undefined or empty strings from array of objects in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60552032/filtering-undefined-or-empty-strings-from-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: It seems to be working as expected and removing empty string.What is the problem?

Comment: Do you want to filter out the empty array entries, or the entries with an empty date property?

Comment: If you want to actually learn about what you are doing there instead of just copy&pasting, this can get you started: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRgD1yVwIvE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a few adjustments:

- Check that `o.date` is truthy (not `null`, `undefined`, `false`, 0, `""`...), by adding `o.date &&`
- Use a full object literal (instead of the ES6 shortcut) to defined other names for the properties, and adapt the `sort` callback accordingly

```js
var array = [{ date: " ", bus_name: 'Thomas #1', driver_name: 'Sam', time_start: '9AM', time_end: '5PM' }, { date: '2012-02-11', bus_name: 'Thomas #2', driver_name: 'Samantha', time_start: '8AM', time_end: '4PM' }, { date: '2011-02-02', bus_name: 'Thomas #3', driver_name: 'Peter', time_start: '12PM', time_end: '7PM' }, { date: '2010-06-04', bus_name: 'Thomas #4', driver_name: 'Eddie', time_start: '11AM', time_end: '6PM' }, { date: " ", bus_name: 'Thomas #5', driver_name: 'Raul', time_start: '4AM', time_end: '1PM' }, { date: '2014-04-03', bus_name: 'Thomas #6', driver_name: 'Jessie', time_start: '5AM', time_end: '2PM' }],
    result = array
        .filter(o => o.date && o.date !== ' ')
        .map(({ date, bus_name }) => ({ arrival: date, busName: bus_name }))
        .sort((a, b) => a.arrival.localeCompare(b.arrival));

console.log(result);
```

NB: I used `arrival` as name, as using a name that starts with a capital (like `Date`) is not very common practice -- initial capitals are more often reserved for names of constructors/classes